# Fast EXISTS in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

What is the fastest way to check if a value exists in a data.table?.
Suppose that

- dt is a data.table of n columns with k columns being the key
- keys is a list, or a value, or a data.table, or anything that can be used in
  the `i` argument of `[.data.table`

I'm currently doing

```
NROW(dt[keys,nomatch=0])!=0
```

Is there anything faster?

Example

```
require(data.table)
iniDate = as.Date("2000-01-01")
theData = data.table(a = LETTERS, d = seq(from=iniDate ,to= iniDate + length(LETTERS)*3000-1,by="day"))
theKeys = data.table(a = c("J","M","T"), d = as.Date(c("2005-01-20","2005-05-20","2013-01-12")))
setkey(theData,a,d)
NROW(theData[theKeys],nomatch=0)!=0
```

Comment: it's always nicer to give an example to show what you're trying to do. You say "a value". And are you checking for only one value? Also are you checking in only one column of the data.table `dt`? Is "keys" a 1-column data.table? As such I find this question vague.

Comment: @Arun Sorry for the vagueness, hope the recent edit helps. I'm looking for a general solution, not just for the case where the i argument is a value or the key is just one column

Comment: you'll have to explain by editing your question a bit more detailed than that.

Comment: @Arun added an example, hope that helps. Notwithstanding that, your answer is accepted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: In addition to `nomatch=0`, I think `mult="first"` would help speed it even more.

Long answer: Assuming that you want to check if a value (or more than 1 value) is present in the *key* column of a `data.table` or not, this seems to be much faster. The only assumption here is that the data.table has only 1 key column (as this is quite ambiguous to me).

```
my.values = c(1:100, 1000)
require(data.table)
set.seed(45)
DT <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(2e4, 1e6*100, replace=TRUE), ncol=100))
setkey(DT, "V1")
# the data.table way
system.time(all(my.values %in% .subset2(DT[J(my.values), mult="first", nomatch=0], "V1")))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.006   0.000   0.006 

# vector (scan) approach
system.time(all(my.values %in% .subset2(DT, "V1")))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.037   0.000   0.038
```

You can change `all` to `any` if you want to check if at least 1 value is present in the subset or not. The only difference between the two is that you first `subset` using `data.table`'s approach (taking advantage of `key` and `mult` argument). As you can see the it's extremely faster (and also scales well). And then to retrieve the key columns from the subset (call it `the_subset`),

```
.subset2(the_subset, "V1") (or) the_subset$V1 (or) the_subset[["V1"]]
```

But, `the_subset[, V1]` will be slower.

Of course the same idea could be extended to many columns as well, but I'll have to know exactly what you want to do after.

Comment: Thanks Arun, just retrieving the first result will surely speed up the computations

Comment: I'm struggling to try to extend this answer to multiple key columns right now.

Answer (score 3):

How about the base R idiom:

```
any(my.value %in% my.vector)
```

This is not a `data.table` specific idiom but is quite efficient I believe.

Comment: `any(my.value == my.vector)` is faster in my testing, albeit only 0.3s faster when `my.vector` is 10M values long.

Comment: Bummer! Sorry to be of only marginal help. :D

Comment: @thelatemail presumably `my.value` is of length greater than 1 since it's called `keys` in the OP.

Comment: @thelatemail: Eh! I read that you meant `==` is faster than `%in%` only now! Plus, I thought you are the person asking the question. Apologies, it is too late in my part of the world.