# What are the algorithmic/programming optimizations that make data.table fast?

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, data.table

I have done some searching around the Internet and SO looking for an introduction or analysis of what makes `data.table` so fast, but I've only found a lot of (very helpful) manuals, no breakdown of what goes into the programming. (I am more or less completely floored that I can't locate a published paper for `data.table`, not even something from JStatSoft.)

I've had an algorithms class so I know about sorts and linked lists and binary trees and such, but I don't want to make any amateur guesses (especially when I go to explain to academic people why it's a good idea to use it). Can anyone offer a short, topical summary with references? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039335/what-is-the-purpose-of-setting-a-key-in-data-table) references a slide presentation which is cool, but the info comes in pieces (and even the documentation for, say, `setkey()` doesn't cite a `data.table` reference, but goes to Wikipedia).

What I am looking for is something that is both **not** the source code and **not** a list of Wikipedia topics, but an ideally "official", sourced answer (thus making it canonical, which could help a lot with [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320284/subsetting-a-data-table-by-range-making-use-of-binary-search) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331684/fast-exists-in-data-table?rq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331684/fast-exists-in-data-table?rq=1) [orbiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508482/what-does-sd-stand-for-in-data-table-in-r?rq=1) [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039335/what-is-the-purpose-of-setting-a-key-in-data-table?rq=1) this topic).

(It would be great if there was a technical paper out there I could cite for this (the `citation()` for `data.table` is just the manual, but of course it's not directly relevant to the question as far as SO is concerned.)

Comment: Darn, I thought this was an okay fit for the site. What did I miss?

Comment: Not my downvote, but "why is `data.table` so great" is pretty subjective, also "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow" [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Definitely, the technical paper is just my thing. I'll change the wording of the question so it doesn't gush so much.

Comment: +1 I hope Arun or Matt will write a nice canonical answer. I expect that it will include assignment by reference / overallocation, fast sorting and binary search.

Comment: useful, but still doesn't seem to be within the scope of the site to me ("specific programming questions")

Comment: Do you think it would be specific if I asked for an answer that linked each optimization to a named use case? the docs for `data.table` are already sort of written that way.

Comment: I don't think it's off-topic per se, since it's clearly about "software algorithms" in a sense. The problem I see is that it asks for external sources, which seems somewhat off-topic. Maybe if you reformulate your question to be a bit more technical and ask for the answer directly, rather than a reference to the answer. It would also help to restrict yourself to a specific operation, because the question as such is really very broad

Comment: Well, yes, my personal benefit is the sources, but the site's benefit is that the answer is sourced, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. SO wants to be self-contained. And good answers often make marvelous sources in itself. Of course a good answer could contain references as well, for further reading, but it should contain all the relevant information to answer the specific question